Adminer error: "Warning: Trying to access array offset on null"
I'm encountering an error in Adminer while managing the database for my Shopware store. The error message is:
Warning: Trying to access array offset on null in /usr/share/adminer/latest.php on line 1777
Despite this error in Adminer, my Shopware store is functioning normally. I can place orders without any issues, and there are no errors in the console output or the browser inspector.
Additional details:

Shopware version: 6.6.4.1
Adminer version: latest
PHP version: 8.2
Database type: MySQL
Database version: latest

I've already verified that:

The store is working correctly, including order placement.
There are no visible errors in the browser console or inspector.
The database connection seems to be working as the store can read/write data.

Questions:

What could be causing this error in Adminer while the store itself is working fine?
How can I troubleshoot this issue further?
Are there any known compatibility issues between Adminer and Shopware that could cause this?

Any insights or troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated.

A warning is not an error. It's a warning. Have you checked Line 1777 of /usr/share/adminer/latest.php?

@maiorano84 That may be true in general, but anything that causes this warning is almost certainly a bug.

Since the error is happening in a third-party application, this isn't a programming problem for you. You should report the problem to the Adminer team.

What does this have to do with Shopware? The problem isn't happening in your PHP application that uses it, it's happening in a totally unrelated application.

This question is similar to: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", "Warning: Undefined array key", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I think I have found a solution to this? Seems like this warning was already being raised but then being suppressed in the adminer.php script. However it was being suppressed via a text match, and the text content of the warning has changed in PHP 8.3.
To fix, try opening up the source code and changing:
'~^(Trying to access array offset on value of type null|Undefined array key)~' (was on line 10 for me in a preg_match(...), just before the only usage of error_reporting.
to:
'~^(Trying to access array offset on null|Undefined array key)~'
This seemed to work for me!

This is my solution:
This happened because I was using a version of php with a version of shopware which was not compatible. No matter what it says online, all php versions that are written are compatible are actually not, especially if you are using the latest shopware versions.
My recommendation is to use a php version with a shopware version that you for sure know will work.

How does this solve the question you've asked? "I'm encountering an error in Adminer" vs Shopware?
